# How to get seconds from hours and minutes

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, timezone

I am using time picker compose and I want to get seconds from it, but what I get is *hours* and *minutes* (23:50).

I want to convert this to get 1692139800000 which is equal to `Tuesday, 15 August 2023 23:50:00`

Now time 18:06 leaving 17hr 59 min 12:05AM - 1692183900000 - Wednesday, 16 August 2023 12:05:00

What I have so far:

```
fun getMillisFromHrsMins(clock: Clock, timeZoneId: ZoneId) {
    val hours = 12
    val minutes = 5
    val targetDaySeconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 // Seconds from midnight 43500
    val date = LocalDateTime.now(clock)
    val nowDaySeconds = date.toLocalTime().toSecondOfDay() // Seconds at this time 65432

    if (targetDaySeconds >= nowDaySeconds) {

    } else {

        val newPastSeconds = nowToMidnightSeconds(timeZoneId) + targetDaySeconds // 43500
        // Is it possible to get 1692183900000 value with above information please
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Updated Code:

```
import java.time.Clock
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

fun getMillisFromHrsMins(clock: Clock, timeZoneId: ZoneId) {
    val hours = 12
    val minutes = 5
    val targetTime = LocalDateTime.now(clock).withHour(hours).withMinute(minutes)
    
    val now = LocalDateTime.now(clock)
    val targetDateTime = if (targetTime.isBefore(now)) {
        targetTime.plusDays(1) // If the target time is in the past, add one day
    } else {
        targetTime
    }
    
    val milliseconds = targetDateTime.atZone(timeZoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
    println(milliseconds)
}

fun main() {
    val clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone()
    val timeZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault()
    getMillisFromHrsMins(clock, timeZoneId)
}
```

The provided target times are used as placeholders by me as an example. You can replace val hours = 12 and val minutes = 5 with your actual target hours and minutes
according to your need.